# Send notifications between 2 methods

Tags: c#

I have an application which consists of a few projects. One of them is BusinessLogic, and one of them is UI (wpf). UI has a reference to BusinessLogic.

When the app starts, there is a loading screen in which the user can only wait because the data is being processed. In the loading screen there is a user control with a canvas. After the data gets processed, the loading screen closes.

Basically this is how my code looks like:

In UI, in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    ShowLoadingScreen();
    var businessLogic = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBusinessLogic>();
    businessLogic.ProcessData();
    CloseLoadingScreen()
}
```

In the BusinessLogic project, the method for processing data looks like this:

```
public bool ProcessData()
{
    ProcessStudents();
    ProcessParents();
    ProcessTeachers();
    ProcessOthers();
}
```

What I now need to do is this: in the loading screen I need to show status messages: "Processing students", "Processing parents", etc. That means I have to send info from BusinessLogic to UI.

Is this possible and what is the best way to do it?

For now I have 2 ideas:

1. Have a timer started in UI and for every 5 or 10 seconds to check a variable in BusinessLogic. That variable would be an enum with the status.
2. With threads. In UI I'll check the current thread pool and somehow in BusinessLogic I'll open a new thread for the current status.

Comment: You may have a look into the MVVM pattern. It describes exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JPVenson I implement the MVVM pattern in the UI project.

Comment: Then keep it Simple stupid.
Create a String property inside your ViewModel and Bind to it, set it to:"Process Students" and call the method and so on.

Comment: @JPVenson Did you even read the question? ProcessData and ProcessStudents are in one project of the solution, and the view of the loading screen is in another project.

Comment: I did, but the Question explains it self. When you are not able to alter the Business logic to Implement some kind of Reporting ... event based or else ... then you should consider a static waiter with only "Processing" message or simply create an Adapter that do this for you. 
You are talking about an "project". We are not working an project level we are talking about Function calls! that has nothing to do with Projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll implement an interface

```
public interface IProcessNotifier
{
    void AppendNotification(string source, string details); // or anything like it
}
```

This interface should be in your business logic layer (or maybe in some `Core` DLL-project holding all your tools and general purpose enums, classes and interfaces).

Then your UI layer implements this interface and it is passed in parameter in your business logic (which signature changes a little then)

```
public bool ProcessData(IProcessNotifier notifier)
{
    if (notifier == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("notifier");

    notifier.AppendNotification("Init.", "Students");
    ProcessStudents(notifier);

    notifier.AppendNotification("Init.", "Parents");
    ProcessParents(notifier);

    notifier.AppendNotification("Init.", "Teachers");
    ProcessTeachers(notifier);

    notifier.AppendNotification("Init.", "Others");
    ProcessOthers(notifier);
}
```

You could encounter some thread issues depending on how you implemented your `IProcessNotifier` in the UI project.

nota bene: very convinient in Unit testing. You implement an IProcessNotifier class that writes in your console or in a log file and all your logging is done automagically. Maybe adding a `Level` enum as parameter of `AppendNotification` could be useful... but off topic here.

---

*Edit to answer comment*

In your UI project you implement the interface

```
public class SplashScreenNotifier : IProcessNotifier 
{
    // Your SplashScreen must have a ViewModel. Let's say it is of type 'SplahScreenViewModel'
    public SplashScreenNotifier(SplahScreenViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("viewModel");

        this.ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private SplahScreenViewModel ViewModel {get; set;}

    public void AppendNotification(string source, string details)
    {
        // Since you implement MVVM, let's say the 'InfoLine' property is bound to your UI splashscreen Label
        this.ViewModel.InfoLine = string.Format("Processing '{0}' for '{1}'", source, details);
    }
}
```

Then, with a few modifications in your `ShowLoadingScreen(..)` method, you will have:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var splashScreenVM = new SplahScreenViewModel();
    var notifier = new SplashScreenNotifier(splashScreenVM);

    ShowLoadingScreen(splashScreenVM);
    var businessLogic = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBusinessLogic>();

    businessLogic.ProcessData(notifier);

    CloseLoadingScreen()
}
```

Comment: WHat would AppendNotification() do? How will it comunicate with the UI for example that the message has been changed from "Init. students" to "Init. parents"?

Comment: @petko_stankoski see my update. Being in MVVM is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, if the `ViewModel` is inaccessible from your current code, is to use a [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) that works like a callback delegate:

```
public bool ProcessData(Action<string> callback)
{
    if (callback != null)
    {
        callback("doing this");
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
instance.ProcessData( x => this.SetProgress(x) );
```

Or even better, create an `interface` hiding the implementation details. Implement that in your `ViewModel` and pass an instance to the `ProcessData` method.

Comment: I tried your code in a separate app. I have a textblock whose content I want to change in code-behind, like the status msgs in the original question. But only the last message is shown. Here's the code: http://justpaste.it/ig71

Comment: As you can see, the code is the same as in your answer, but it doesnt shown all of the messages, just the last one.

Comment: @petko_stankoski: You code is running synchronous, so all UI actions are done when your method finishes. Try to use a `BackgroundWorker` to start the job, or `Task` and put this in your `SetProgress`: `this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { txtStatusMessage.Text = status; });`

Comment: So basically it comes down to threads or timers, just what I wrote in the question.

Comment: @petko_stankoski: Yes, but your processing goes in the thread. You aren't going to poll the status in a thread.

Comment: @petko_stankoski and Timer is never the way to do what bindings or Tasks or Thread are made for.